# Why I cannot get the facebook album ID ?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What I want to do is create album on facebook and upload photo to the album, now it work to create an album on facebook,but it's not work on uploading photo to album, I dont know why I cannot get the album ID, any solution or idea?

here is my code which is create album and upload photo on facebook

```
<?//At the time of writing it is necessary to enable upload support in the Facebook SDK, you do this with the line:
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

    //Create an album
    $album_details = array(
            'message'=> 'name',
            'name'=> 'name'
    );
    $create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

    //Get album ID of the album you've just created
    $albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
    foreach ($albums["data"] as $album) {
    //Test if the current album name is the one that has just been created
        if($album["name"] == 'name'){
            $album_uid = $album["id"];
        }
    }

    //Upload a photo to album of ID...
    $photo_details = array(
        'message'=> 'test'
    );
    $file='http://scm-l3.technorati.com/11/12/30/59287/google-logo-682-571408a.jpg'; //Example image file
    $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

    $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
    //print_r($upload_photo);
    ?>
```

thanks

Comment: your problem is album_uid or image upload to album..?

Comment: i get the album_id , now the problem is upload image to album

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you could upload file from url, try:

```
$pathToFile = "/some/path/someimage.jpg";
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
............
$create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);
//get the album id
$album_uid = $create_album["id"]; // no need for foreach loop

.....
$args = array('message' => 'Some message');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($pathToFile);  //see realpath use here

$data = $facebook->api('/'. $album_uid . '/photos', 'post', $args);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank for reply, I had change my path and try your code, it still cannot upload the image, I had var_dump my $album_uid, it's work now, just dont know why it not upload in my album

Answer (score 0):

you can not call `realpath` against http file. it's for local files only.
download the file first using `curl`, `wget`, or one of php internal functions like `file_get_contents`/`file_put_contents`.

for example:

```
$file='http://scm-l3.technorati.com/11/12/30/59287/google-logo-682-571408a.jpg'; //Example image file
$output = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'blex_');
$cmd = "wget -q \"$file\" -O $output";
exec($cmd);
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($output);
```