# how can i have the id of the album that i have just created?

Tags: php, facebook

i have my own app that its supposed to create a photo album (if this album doesn't exist already) and upload an image.

whenever you dont have the photo album you are supposed to have (created by the app) it creates the photo album but it doesn't upload the picture to this album, it only upload the picture the second time you run the script.

so im guessing im not being able to have my new album's id the first round. How can i have my new album's id?

regards!

Answer (score 2):

There are two function that return this value:

```
Php function -> mysqli_insert_id()

Mysql function ->LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Answer (score 1):

As your question is tagged with `facebook`, I'm assuming by your album-creation comments you mean you're creating an album with Facebook's API?

If that's the case, you could use something similar to the code from [Why I cannot get the facebook album ID ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787916/why-i-cannot-get-the-facebook-album-id):

```
$create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);
//get the album id
$album_uid = $create_album["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Put that right after your INSERT query and you have access to the ID.

Comment: i have divided this in three php, first takes all info (if its logged to facebook, imagge selected, etc) second php takes a look to albums and if its not there it creates the album and stores the album id in a session varaible, then the third php uploads the image to the new album or the old and expected album. :)